# Wait for HeroCard image to load before sending the message

Tags: botframework

How can I ensure that the image is loaded before sending the message? I'm currently using the `setTimeout()` function to provide a more natural chat experience along with `session.sendTyping()`. This also somewhat ensures that the message is built properly before being sent, but I still sometimes experience images not being loaded.

The images are hosted in Azure Files and accessed through HTTP with a SAS key.

[image: image not yet loaded]

As shown in the image, the message returns a Hero Card with a blank image.'

**Update: some code for reference**

```
// The function returns a message object with either a Hero Card or a text string 
function addImgToMsg(table) {
    let msg = new builder.Message(session);
    let mainCard = new builder.HeroCard(session);

    // Check if the given DB entry has an image link
    if (table.img) {
        mainCard.images([
            builder.CardImage.create(session, 'link_to_my_image')
        ]);
    }

    // Attach the Hero Card to the message if has gotten any content
    if (mainCard.data.content.images) {
        msg.attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel);
        msg.attachments([mainCard]);
    } else {
        msg.text('No was image provided.')
    }

    return msg;
}
```

Comment: BotFramework only sends the image url to the channel. It is upto the channel to render it. Maybe channel could not access the image url. Some channels show the text content of the message immediately as soon as it is available, and download image in background, and displaying immediately when download completes, which sometimes takes time. But we cannot control that behavior from botframework. That said, is the code you provided is pseudo code. When checking in DB for image, you should take the necessary action in a callback, otherwise this kind of thing will happen. If needed post actual code

Comment: What channel are you using, and might the files be too big for the channel?  many channels have limits on size

Comment: I'm using the DirectLine channel and the images are between 7-31 KB using PNG and GIF formats. I have rewritten some of the code using promises and haven't encountered any unloaded images yet, but it might just be random if it's up to the channel to render it, like Master Chief said.

Comment: Is it just one or the other (PNG or GIF) that is experiencing the timeouts, or are both image types experiencing the timeouts?

Comment: @BlackSeraph both are experiencing the timeouts.

Comment: What is the client side?  (what code is rendering the image?)